# Why is __init__.py missing for pkgutil-style namespace package?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, python-wheel

The following python library is missing its `__init__.py` file when the wheel is built:

https://github.com/intuit/oauth-pythonclient

https://pypi.org/project/intuit-oauth/

There is an `__init__.py` in the original source code (see the `intuitlib` directory), and it seems to be configured to use the python 2 compatible pkgutil-style namespace packages as described here:

https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#pkgutil-style-namespace-packages

I cloned the git repo, and ran this command to build the wheel myself using python 2.7:
`python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`

Since my application is running Python 2.7, it fails without the `__init__.py` file. What is misconfigured in that project that is omitting the `__init__.py` file in the build?